# Throwing errors inside of a MySQL procedure?

Tags: mysql

I've read ways to throw fake errors with custom messages, however I'm talking about regular MySQL errors. My SQL code is working fine when executed as a basic INSERT statement, however while moving it to a procedure it's not inserting, or returning any values.

Here's the code:

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE enck VARCHAR(40);

    SET token = null;
    SET enck = uuid();

    INSERT INTO `accounts` (`email_address`, `password`, `encry_key`, `session_key`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `birthdate`, `latitude`, `longitude`) VALUES (email_in, MD5(CONCAT(pass_in, MD5(enck))), enck, uuid(), name_in, last_in, birth_in, lat_in, long_in);

    SELECT session_key INTO token FROM accounts WHERE email_address = email_in;

END
```

I know using MD5 for passwords isn't the best approach, but that's not what my question is about, so please refrain from statements about it.

Comment: Can we make comments about the fact you are using the output of md5 as a salt for the md5 hash for no good reason?

Comment: Could be because the most popular solution for password cryptology in low level web applications is `md5(md5(pass).md5(salt))`